# How do you use a function in a namespace?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following Namespace with 2 functions in it that I want to use, but I'm not sure how I access them?

I  tried importing ("using" for C#) but those 2 functions arent in the namespace.

Do I have to create a class and create those functions myself?

[image]

The weird thing is, those 2 functions are found within a different namespace:

[image]

Regardless of where it is, how would I turn these into functions I can call from my code?

When I try to access those functions in my code, they don't know up :

[image]

Comment: Please add your code snippets for more clarity. You cannot have functions in the namespace directly.

Comment: Is this C#? Doesn't look like it. Don't tag it as C#. Also, MathService isn't a namespace.

Comment: I tagged it as C# because the library is in C#. I've been converting C# to VB.NET so I thought this is something that's easier to do in C# but different to do in VB.NET

Comment: Just create an instance of `MathService`, as you would any other class. It's not really "different to do in VB.NET".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting a bit confused.  It's understandable with namespaces.
Gds.GoogleMap.UltimatePlus.Math.Mathservice is *not* a namespace name.  The namespace name is **Gds.GoogleMap.UltimatePlus.Math**  .  MathService is the *class* name.

If you put the statement

```
using Gds.GoogleMap.UltimatePlus.Math;
```

at the top of your file then all you need to do to declare a new object is to say:

```
MathService myService = new MathService();
```

assuming it has  a default constructor.

Give it a try.

Comment: And obviously the VB.NET equivalent code is `Imports Gds.GoogleMap.UltimatePlus.Math` and `Dim myService  As New MathService`

Comment: I tried that for VB.net, imported the .Math and `Dim MyService As New MathService` but I don't have to do `Dim myService As New MathService`

I just need to do `Dim MyService as MathService` apparently because it does not take new.

Comment: You're welcome.  I had the same problem myself when starting out with C#, after years programming VB6

Comment: You might also be experience a *static class*.  Static classes cannot be instantiated with the **new** keyword. You just call them by **ClassName.Method()**.  No need to declare a new instance.  Treat them as if there were always one instance of the class hanging around and always available.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but for some reason, I'm getting `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when I try converting my LatLng into a Point. The `ConvertLatLngToPoint` takes a `LatLng(double lat, double lng)` so what I did was :
`Dim lll As LatLng = New LatLng(Lat, Lng)` `Dim sp As New Point` `sp = myService .ConvertLatLngToPoint(lll)`

Comment: A static class in C# is equivalent to a module in VB.  The only difference is that you need to provide the class name to access a member of a static class where you don't have to provide the module name in VB.  A VB module is actually implemented as a static class when compiled.

Comment: I would start by assuming that `MathService` is a static class intended to group free functions, in which case trying to declare an instance of it will do more harm than good (e.g. the NullRefException in the most recent comment from the OP).

Comment: @Craig , How would I fix it or use it?

Comment: You don't fix it.  You just call it.  **ClassName.MethodName()**.  That's it, assuming you've put a **using Namespace.SubNameSpace...** statement at the top of your file